# how to convert my c# array to json?

Tags: c#, json, listview, http, xamarin.android

I was trying to use json for my mobile app, uploadt the file to file hosting site at retrieve it using http. Now I'm having a problem because I'm trying to pass it in a list view and it doesnt retrieve any data. I already test it in jsontoc# but I still think that there's something wrong with my json.. can you tell me if I'm doing it right or can you tell me whats wrong with it?

my json

```
[
{
"Mountains": [
  {
    "MtName": "TALAMITAM",
    "Masl":  630,
    "Difficulty": 3,
    "Island":  1
    },
    {
    "MtName": "ALTO PEAK",
    "Masl":  1332,
    "Difficulty": 6,
    "Island": 2
    },
    {
    "MtName": "CANDALAGA",
    "Masl":  1232,
    "Difficulty": 7,
    "Island": 3
    }       
  ]
} 
]
```

and here is my array in c#

```
 public static List<Mountain> MountainList = new List<Mountain>()
        {

            new Mountain()
            {
                MtName = "ALTO PEAK",
                Masl = 1332,
                Difficulty = 6,
                Island = 2
            },
            new Mountain()
            {
                MtName = "APO",
                Masl = 2956,
                Difficulty = 7,
                Island = 3                   
            },
            new Mountain()
            {
                MtName = "CANDALAGA",
                Masl = 1232,
                Difficulty = 7,
                Island = 3                   
            },              
        }
```

Comment: use some library such as [Newtonsoft.Json](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Comment: already did sir :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON for a list of the class Mountain is

```
[
  {
    "MtName": "TALAMITAM",
    "Masl":  630,
    "Difficulty": 3,
    "Island":  1
  },
  {
    "MtName": "ALTO PEAK",
    "Masl":  1332,
    "Difficulty": 6,
    "Island": 2
  },
  {
    "MtName": "CANDALAGA",
    "Masl":  1232,
    "Difficulty": 7,
    "Island": 3
  }       
]
```

The JSON you have is an array of a class that contains a property `public List<Mountain> MountainList;`

Comment: so i do not have to write the "Mountains" part?

Comment: No, you do not have to write the mountain part.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON has this format:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class Class1
{
    public Mountain[] Mountains { get; set; }
}

public class Mountain
{
    public string MtName { get; set; }
    public int Masl { get; set; }
    public int Difficulty { get; set; }
    public int Island { get; set; }
}
```

You have an array of `Mountains` so it will not conform to the format. Try using the above format and then use [Json.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) to convert your class to JSON like this:

```
var ro = new Rootobject();
// more code here to populate the ro properties
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ro);
```

Comment: can you show me whats the right format for my json? like the first answer? because thats what im looking for.. thanks for answering :D